# Ubuntu 14.04: Unable to locate package php7.0-zip

Tags: php, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, laravel-5.4, php-7.0

I am not being able to install package php7.0-zip. The error I get after doing

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip
```

Is:

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   E: Unable to locate package php7.0-zip
>   E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0-zip'

This is for an Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS. My PHP version is 7.0.17.

I tried doing:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
```

And still getting the same "unable to locate" error.

I expect to solve my "Fatal error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in" in Laravel 5.4, after installing zip package.

Comment: You can have the full list of php7.0 packages available on the repository : sudo apt-cache search php7.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I couldn't find the package because I was using Ubuntu 14.04, and as is an unsupported Ubuntu version, there is no more php packages in the repository.

Comment: Thanks, on Ubunut18 the packages are available. On Debian 10 nope, just a reference from php-zip to php7.2-zip, should try yet adding via `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` . Yet the package was in spite of that somehow preinstalled there into php.

Answer (score 8):

if you do `sudo apt-cache search php7.0-*` you should get a list of all packages.

The zip module should be at the bottom

[image: bash output]

If it isn't there you might wish to try

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php && sudo apt-get update` instead of just `add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: No, -zip is not there. I run everything as root, so I run sudo add-apt.....ondrej and I still dont get the package. Thanks

Comment: Why... why would you run everything as root.... anyways, have you tried cleaning the apt-cache? https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2017/10/09/how-to-clean-the-apt-cache/